# WPF optical style of dynamically created MenuItem-Separator in MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have have a `MenuItem` that creates its sub-menu-items dynamicly from the `ItemsSource`-property.

For grouping, I have Separators in the menu. The separator is created for each null-entry in the ItemsSource-collection by a ControlTemplate of the `MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle`.

This works fine, however has the separator not the same optical style as the other separators have which are placed in a the Items-collection of a menu.

Is there a way to change the look of the separator so that it looks equal to the "normal" menu-item-separators?

Here is the code I use:

```
<MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
  <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Title}"/>
    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding }" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Template" >
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Separator /> <!-- THIS SEPARATOR IS NOT SHOWN AS COMMON MENUITEM-SEPARATORS ARE -->
                    </ControlTemplate>                                        
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>                            
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a Style that is declared in System.Resources with [MenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.separatorstylekey.aspx) as the key. The parent MenuItem normally sets the style on children of type Separator, but since yours is a MenuItem, it won't, so you will have to do it manually:

```
<Separator Style="{StaticResource {x:Static MenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey}}" />
```

You may also want to read Bea Stollnitz's blog entry ["How do I insert Separator objects in a data bound MenuItem?"](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=23) for another approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the Seperator in a MenuItem

```
<ControlTemplate>
  <MenuItem>
    <MenuItem.Header>
      <Separator />
    </MenuItem.Header>
  </MenuItem>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is a good idea but sadly it does not help. The separator looks equal but has as child additionally a MenuItem which is selectable (what makes the separator selectable in the end, if not disabled).