# WPF string collection binding, need to convert to an element type

Tags: wpf, data-binding, menuitem, stringcollection

I have a string collection that is bound to a MenuItem as it's ItemsSource (the strings are user added bookmarks representing folder paths). However, within the string collection I might have a string of, say, hyphens ("----") that I want to be displayed as a Separator element.  However, the Separator is different from a MenuItem element.  I need some way to convert the applicable string to a Separator element.

What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this answer [WPF optical style of dynamically created MenuItem-Separator in MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675198/wpf-optical-style-of-dynamically-created-menuitem-separator-in-mvvm)

and this blog post:
http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/440#.UJ2_lofaW_w

Basically what you need to do is to to add the "separator" item as an item in the source collection.